# I've been trying to use for loop via user input but for some reason it neither shows the error nor shows the output

Tags: javascript, html, forms, loops, dom

I've been trying to use for loop via user input but for some reason it neither shows the error nor shows the output. here is my code below:-

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>js recap</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="addform">
    <input type="number" name="text" id="text">
  </form>

<!-- START JAVASCRIPT -->

  <script>
    const addform = document.querySelector('.addform');

    addform.addEventListener('submit', e => {
      const todos = addform.text.value.trim();
      e.preventDefault();
      if (todos === typeof Number) {
        for (let i = 0; i <= todos; i++) {
          console.log(i);
        }
      }
    });
  </script>

<!-- END JAVASCRIPT-->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

some notes:

- `e.target.value.trim()` returns a string
- use `typeof todos === "number"` or you can use `!isNaN(todos)` to check if a variable is a type of number ( `isNaN` means is not a number add the negation to it `!isNaN` to check if its a number )
- `parseInt()` to convert the string retrieved from `e.target.value.trim()` to a number

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>js recap</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="addform">
    <input type="number" name="text" id="text">
  </form>

<!-- START JAVASCRIPT -->

  <script>
    const addform = document.querySelector('.addform');

    addform.addEventListener('submit', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      
      const todos = parseInt(addform.text.value.trim())

      if (typeof todos === "number") {
        for (let i = 0; i <= todos; i++) {
          console.log(i);
        }
      }
    });
  </script>

<!-- END JAVASCRIPT-->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a button to submit your form (click event in this example). You can use parseInt to convert string to a number data type.

```js
var addform = document.querySelector('#text');
var boton = document.querySelector("#boton");

boton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  var todos = parseInt(addform.value.trim());
  e.preventDefault();

  if (typeof todos === 'number') {
    for (let i = 0; i <= todos; i++) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" name="text" id="text">
<button id="boton"> Go </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any value that a user enters via the DOM comes through as text. You need to convert it into a number and then run the loop.

You can do:

```
if( !isNaN( Number(todos) ))
```

The if statement that you have is never true. So the code never executes.

You can check it by adding a console log just for the check.

```
console.log('%c Check the input value.', 'background:grey; padding:10px; color:#fff', typeof todos, todos);
```